# Commit "local" data factory changes to Azure DevOps GIT

Tags: git, azure, azure-data-factory

I've added Azure DevOps Git-integration some weeks ago. 
Somehow, I've changed from Git to "Data Factory" and added some pipelines and datasets.

[image: "local" changes]

When I now change back to git, these new pipelines and datasets are missing.
[image]

How do I now get this changes to the git repo?

Removing and re-adding repo doesn't work.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Seems changes in Data factory mode will not be saved to Git.

But you can try recreating a git repo, and load existing resource to it.
[image: Repository Settings]

Comment: I thought already about it, but I hope there is another option.

Comment: How about export arm template in Data factory mode, and import arm template in your git mode?

Comment: It seems, that the ARM template is imported to the Data Factory mode.

Comment: So you've already tried the above approach? Did you change the last option to create new and checked import existing data factory resources to repository?

Comment: Yes, I tried your approach. That also doesn't work. I copied now the pipelines and datasets by hand.